# How to change the Hostname for my Windows XP OS?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

How to change the Hostname for my Windows XP OS ?

Recently, i have formatted my computer and reinstalled few programming stuffs like SQL etc ..!

At present my host name is like .. ABC-121212HEHX which is unable to remember.

I want to change the hostname to "Former" which was my actual hostname.

And on doing so, whether this is affect my SQL Installation ?

Comment: For considerations with SQL server when renaming the host machine look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/249062/renamed-computer-with-mssql-2005-installed-might-have-broken-something/249075#249075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using this way:

- Click Start, click Control Panel, and
  then click System.
- Click the Computer    Name tab, and
  then click Change
- Type the new computer name in the
  Computername dialog box.

You will need to restart your computer after this.